# How to add a language to vscode web without using yeoman?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I use [github.dev](https://github.dev) for a lot of my programming work because I don't like downloading programs. As such, I would not like to download either the vscode app or yeoman. Can I make my own extension inside github.dev (perhaps using the `.vscode` folder?)? I've read a bunch of documentation, but all of it seems to hinge on using yeoman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Yeoman to create an extension. Yeoman is just a scaffolding tool, and only helps you in the initial process. Instead, you could simply copy/clone any other extension that seems similar to your need, and update it to make it the way you want.

Back to github.dev, unfortunately, you won't be able to use it to develop your extension, simply because it does not allow *debugging*. Without that,  you won't be able to test your extension. Also, you will still need to install [vsce](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension), which is responsible for bundling/publishing the extension.

Instead, you should use services like [Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces) or [Gitpod](https://gitpod.io), because once they provide you a remote server, you could install yeoman and vsce there. But, services like Codespaces and Gitpode uses *desktop-like* extensions, and Github.dev/vscode.dev uses *web-like* extensions, which are a bit different (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/web-extensions)

Hope this helps

Comment: What about using the command `>Developer: Install Web Extension`? Would that allow me to add extensions that way? (I've already experimented a bit with this and discovered that the github.dev csp is being annoying so I've switched to using vscode.dev).

Comment: For example, I could write and host the extension on github, then use that command to run it in vscode.dev?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suppose it won't work. Maybe this comment could give you some direction (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156109#issuecomment-1225763891).

If that's not the case, I suggest you to open an issue in VS Code repo, so the team could take a closer look at your need.